# Ya know what's really nasty?

Tags: discussion

One of the reasons that we close questions here is if they are just about programming issues.

So on both the Software Engineering Stack Exchange and on Stack Overflow, I ask a programming question (about optimization in C or C++) that is quite pertinent about real-time DSP (it's a MIPSy issue) and both places my question gets four downvotes and nasty reaction from the locals.  Finally, in SO, someone actually answered it (after telling me first that my question was crappy.

We might have to deal with programming questions ourselves if the programming guys on SE and SO deem it beneath them.

Answer (score 1):

[Probably prompted by a question that I closed recently.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/89675/80)  What I would like from the SE.SP audience is guidance on distinguishing between what you're talking about and our standard close reason:

> Questions requesting working code written to a specification are
> off-topic as they are unlikely to benefit anyone else. Instead,
> describe the problem you're solving and where you're stuck.

My problem with the specific question I closed was that, after getting a sensible answer, the OP did not engage again at all.  If the answer didn't satisfy the OP and the OP made follow-up comments, or if the OP had marked the answer as correct, I think I'd have less of an issue with it (though the only reason I saw it was because the Community Bot made if visible again because an answer was given that wasn't selected).

So how do we distinguish between "help fix my code" and "code written to a specification" ?

Comment: [Here was my question posted to SO that was actually answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77663099/word-width-before-and-after-multiplication) but only first after some snark.  How is this not a legit question?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Ya, gulpr is an asshole, especially for someone with only a 957 rep on SO. Heck, even **I** have a higher SO rep than that by a factor of 8.

Comment: Well, at least he shown me this [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/), which I had never known about.  I am experimenting with it a little.  Even with the optimizer on, the compiled code still looks suboptimal.  Mostly because of the code to clip the value (which we need for DSP).  Kinda squirrely.  But it came out better than I might have guessed.